# print how many rows contains consecutive elements matching a+b=c

Tags: java

I'm trying to print how many rows contain subarrays (a, b, c) which satisfy `a + b = c`

```
int [][] matrix = {
            {0,**5,2,7**,0,0},
            {6,0,2, 1,-5,5},
            {8,5,**1,1,2**,-2},
            {3,-1,-5,-3,-4,-2}
    };
```

this is the matrix in question it has only two sums so my program should print 2 , but somehow i miss something , the program should only print the rows that contain a sum of numbers not matter how many they are on a row

```
int [][] matrix = {
            {0,5,2,7,9,0},
            {6,0,2, 1,-5,5},
            {8,5,1,1,2,-2},
            {3,-1,-5,-3,-4,-2}
    };
```

for example here we have 3 sums, but my program should print 2 anyway

```
public static int rowSumsOfThree(int [][] matrix) {
    int count = 0 ;
    if (matrix.length != 0 ) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < matrix.length ; i++) {
          for (int j = 0 ; j < matrix[0].length-2 ; j++)
            if (matrix[i][j] + matrix[i][j+1] == matrix[i][j+2]) {
              count++;
              break;
            }
    }}
    return count; 
}
```

this is my code so far , i know it's maybe some stupid mistake i make , if you can provide some explanation it is greatly appreciated , thank you all

Maybe my english is bad , I need to create a method that sums the elements within an array as

```
int [] matrix = {{2,3,4,7,8,3,2},
                       {1,23,4,2,2,}};
```

given this matrix , i need to sum them like this , first two elements = the third , second and third element = the fourth and so on , if the algorithm checks than it should return on how many rows it checks  , first matrix should be 2 , second matrix should be 1 ; i hope i explained better

EDIT : Use of break solved my problem ! It will count only one sum per row , even if there are more per row , therefor count will be equal also to the numbers of rows. thank you for the help

Comment: `if(matrix.length!=0)` not needed, the `for` will do the same thing.

Comment: Your inner loop (`j`) does not appear to sum a row.  I think you need to explain what you want to do first, I don't think 'sum' is it.

Comment: it is needed because if the matrix is zero the method should return -1 ,  :)

Comment: How is `1` the sum of an empty set?

Comment: markspace , sum of elements within the row , i want to print how many rows contain sum of elements within the row , if a row has 1,2,3,4,4,8 , for 4+4 = 8 , the  row contains a sum of elements therefor the index of the row should be printed

Comment: It will always return last sum rowIndex (for which the "if" is true) because "rowIndex" variable will always be the last sum rowIndex. Do yo want to return the variable "count" ?  If you want to return all the matching rows - you need to have an array to contain more than 1 rowIndex.

Comment: Ari I want to return the sum of the indexes in witch the if statement is true

Answer (score 0):

As ari said, your return statement should be:

```
return count;
```

not

```
return rowIndex;
```

It's a very simple bug, consider deleting your question.

Comment: Why delete it , it's a very legitimate exercise , (print how many rows a sum like that can be found) . It's true rowIndex should be deleted , and a break should be added , I belive i explained very well what i was looking for! in any case thank you for the help